# asp.net mvc vs php mvc vs just php for cafepress type site

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I dont have experience in web programming. I so far I coded in c++ only. If I wanted to build a site similar in functionality to cafepress.com which route would be most suitable for me?
asp.net mvc or php mvc or just php?

Granted I am new at this, still the amount of options is overwhelming to a newbie. And there is no decent guideline as to pick which is more suitable for what kind of projects?

Since I am new at this, I have to learn one of these things. But I don't want to waste my time only to see these things go out of fashion. So, I am looking for these qualities :

- must not go out of fashion in a few years. By this I mean, something that is hyped just because its new and has not found a universal acceptance yet
- simple, easy to learn and don't over complicate
- do not abstract how web works (asp.net webforms....ahem)
- can be done by a small group 2-3 guys

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to go for Cakephp or codeigniter which are damn good for making large and maintainable sites. PHP is open-source, cross-platform, has good community support to php and above mentioned frameworks, something not there in asp.net. Also in asp.net security holes are found regularly.

Answer (score 1):

I like ASP.Net MVC so i would recommend that because C# is awesome and Visual Studio is the best IDE. But you should look at the languages and tools and figure out what suites you.